# Merging various Groovy files of Jenkins shared library in a single

Tags: jenkins, groovy, jenkins-groovy

I am new to Jenkins Shared Library. Setup a shared library which is having some `.groovy` related to cleaning nuget packages, restoring nuget packages, building & publishing `.net core` projects. Now i want a single `.groovy` file in my shared library which will call the functions of each of these `.groovy` file. For e.g. following is the groovy script for nuget clean

```
def call(String projectPath){
  bat "dotnet clean ${projectPath} --configuration Release"
  bat "dotnet nuget locals all --clear"
}
```

Following is the groovy script for nuget restore

```
def call(String nugetConfig, String projectPath){
  bat "dotnet restore --no-cache --configfile ${nugetConfig} ${projectPath}"
}
```

Now i want a groovy script which will call both these groovy scripts functions in a single groovy file which will again remain in the same Jenkins shared library.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Just create a third groovy file `dotnet.grrovy` and inside it just call functions from other files: `def call(String projectPath, String nugetConfig, String projectPath) { clean(projectPath); restore(nugetConfig, projectPath)}` assuming clean and restore are the 2 other files.

Comment: Thanks. It solves my problem. I was doing same typo mistake.